# Unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occured in System.Data.dll

Tags: vb.net, oledb, oledbexception

I'm getting an error in this code, designed to create records in an Access Database, but can't seem to work out why.

```
Option Explicit On
Option Strict On

Imports System.Data.OleDb

'Name:          CustomerController.vb
'Description:   Class acting as intermediary between the Customer Form and Customer table
'               Contains Most of the CRUD business Logic
'Author:        Alastair McIntyre
'Date:          12/04/2015

Public Class CustomerController
    Public Const CONNECTION_STRING As String = "provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=assignment 1.accdb"

    Public Function insertCustomer(ByVal htCustomer As Hashtable) As Integer

        Dim oConnection As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(CONNECTION_STRING)
        Dim iNumRows As Integer
        Try
            Debug.Print("Connection string: " & oConnection.ConnectionString)

            oConnection.Open()
            Dim oCommand As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand
            oCommand.Connection = oConnection

            oCommand.CommandText = _
                "INSERT INTO customer (title, gender, firstname, lastname, phone, address, email, dob) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);"

            oCommand.Parameters.Add("title", OleDbType.VarChar, 255)
            oCommand.Parameters.Add("gender", OleDbType.VarChar, 255)
            oCommand.Parameters.Add("firstname", OleDbType.VarChar, 255)
            oCommand.Parameters.Add("lastname", OleDbType.VarChar, 255)
            oCommand.Parameters.Add("phone", OleDbType.Integer, 11)
            oCommand.Parameters.Add("address", OleDbType.VarChar, 255)
            oCommand.Parameters.Add("email", OleDbType.VarChar, 255)
            oCommand.Parameters.Add("dob", OleDbType.Integer, 8)

            oCommand.Parameters("title").Value = CStr(htCustomer("title"))
            oCommand.Parameters("gender").Value = CStr(htCustomer("gender"))
            oCommand.Parameters("firstname").Value = CStr(htCustomer("firstname"))
            oCommand.Parameters("lastname").Value = CStr(htCustomer("lastname"))
            oCommand.Parameters("phone").Value = CInt(htCustomer("phone"))
            oCommand.Parameters("address").Value = CStr(htCustomer("address"))
            oCommand.Parameters("email").Value = CStr(htCustomer("email"))

            oCommand.Prepare()

            iNumRows = oCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Debug.Print(CStr(iNumRows))

            Debug.Print("The record was insterted")
            'Catch ex As Exception
            'Debug.Print("Error: " & ex.Message)
            'MsgBox("An error occured. The record wasn't inserted")
        Finally
            oConnection.Close()
        End Try

        Return iNumRows
    End Function
End Class
```

After commenting out the error message to try and debug the error, I've found the error occurs here "https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQgBJ.png" When this occurs in Debub mode, the application crashes, and does not create a record in the linked database

Comment: In the future please include the error message and where it happens in your post, not a link to a picture of the error

Answer (score 1):

Read the error message:

> Parameter ?_8 has no default value.

Your query has 8 parameter placeholders:

```
oCommand.CommandText = _
            "INSERT INTO customer (title, gender, firstname, lastname, phone, address, email, dob) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);"
```

Then you add 8 parameters:

```
oCommand.Parameters.Add("title", OleDbType.VarChar, 255)
oCommand.Parameters.Add("gender", OleDbType.VarChar, 255) 
oCommand.Parameters.Add("firstname", OleDbType.VarChar, 255)
oCommand.Parameters.Add("lastname", OleDbType.VarChar, 255)
oCommand.Parameters.Add("phone", OleDbType.Integer, 11)
oCommand.Parameters.Add("address", OleDbType.VarChar, 255)
oCommand.Parameters.Add("email", OleDbType.VarChar, 255)
oCommand.Parameters.Add("dob", OleDbType.Integer, 8)
```

Then... you set 7 values:

```
oCommand.Parameters("title").Value = CStr(htCustomer("title"))
oCommand.Parameters("gender").Value = CStr(htCustomer("gender"))
oCommand.Parameters("firstname").Value = CStr(htCustomer("firstname"))
oCommand.Parameters("lastname").Value = CStr(htCustomer("lastname"))
oCommand.Parameters("phone").Value = CInt(htCustomer("phone"))
oCommand.Parameters("address").Value = CStr(htCustomer("address"))
oCommand.Parameters("email").Value = CStr(htCustomer("email"))
```

You need to set a value for the 8th parameter ("dob").

(Side note: Phone and DOB probably shouldn't be *integers* since they're not integer values.  Phone is a text value, DOB is a date value.)

Comment: Thanks for the fresh eyes, that fixed it. Such a simple error, but after working on it for so long, I just couldn't see it.